# calabash: touch UITextView but didn't trigger delegate shouldChangeCharactersInRange

Tags: ios7, automation, calabash

In iOS 7 calabash tried touch() query on text view but it didn't trigger  delegate shouldChangeCharactersInRange. so I'm unable to type text using keyboard_enter_text()

I can set text to a text view using `set_text ()` method, 
like this

`query("textView index:#{index}", setText:"#{text}")`

But it didn't trigger the delegate methods.
Does anyone have a solution for this please share.

Comment: This is the only discussion I found 
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/calabash-ios/UITextViewRs2,623.14 ($20)iosRs27,149.45 ($207)/calabash-ios/QnwtOrDCu_w/ePQm9JJu3KEJ

Answer (score 0):

I used this for the solution. I had to call "touch" event twice in order to work. It was a out of the blue solution. but first check it using once

```
def set_text_to_textview_num(text,index)
  index = index.to_i
  if (index>=0)
    touch(isValidElement("view:'UITextView' index:#{index}"))
    touch(isValidElement("view:'UITextView' index:#{index}"))
    sleep(0.4)
    wait_for_keyboard
    sleep(0.2)
    keyboard_enter_text("#{text}")
    done
    sleep(0.3)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted the the topic that you tried to link to in your comment.

This is the correct URL (shortened) you sited in your comment:  http://goo.gl/3smo72

Short answer:  use `keyboard_enter_text`

`set_text` has been deprecated since 0.9.145 (calabash is now at 0.9.167).

The solution I gave in my post was a hack in response to Apple silently dropping support for playback/record which broke calabash's ability to perform touch events in iOS 7.

In the code you posted can be replaced with

```
wait_for_elements_exist(["textView index:#{index.to_i}"])
touch("textView index:#{index}")
wait_for_keyboard
keyboard_enter_text(text)
tap_keyboard_action_key
# sleep or wait for something else like the keyboard to disappear
```

Comment: Thanks Jmoody. Actually, what happen was after I call touch event on UITextVIew the keyboard didn't show up so I was unable to use "keyboard_enter_text" the solution was calling the touch event twice.

Comment: Please update the title of your question since it does not accurately describe the problem you were having.  There is no reason why should have to touch the UITextView 2x.  I suspect there is a problem in your Objective-C code.